# Is there any important difference between set dbs=currentdb() and using currentDB() directly?

Tags: ms-access

I have inherited a lot of code that is essentially like this:

```
dim dbs as dao.database
set dbs = currentdb()
dbs.execute "Some SQL string"
set dbs = nothing
```

Is there any reason not to recode it as:

```
currentdb().execute "some  SQL string"
```

(I know that if I want to use .recordsaffected, currentdb().recordsaffected won't yield usable results).

Are there any benefits from recoding it, other than simplifying the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply using `CurrentDb.Whatever` is a tempting shortcut, but there are quite a few circumstances where it causes strange behaviour. That's because `CurrentDb` is not an Object itself, it is a Function that returns a copy of the current Database object.

Years ago I swore off trying to use `CurrentDb` like it was an Object after the umpteenth time I was debugging code that I *knew* was "right", and it was... once I created a proper `DAO.Database` object (`Set cdb = CurrentDb`) and used `cdb.Whatever` instead of `CurrentDb.Whatever`.

Comment: What about when you use it only to set up a recordset?  ie. set rst = currentdb.openrecordset()...

Comment: @HelloW For production code I always create a proper DAO.Database object regardless of its intended use. Occasionally for "throw-away" code I'll get lazy and use `CurrentDb.Whatever` but in my opinion it's a bad habit. Any supposed gains in performance or code readability are really negligible, and since there *are* circumstances where using `CurrentDb.Whatever` gets weird I'd rather be consistent and not have to remember when it works and when it doesn't.